# How to write to stdin of a service

Tags: systemd

I have a service running which has a CLI connected to stdin.  When I `ssh` into the machine, I'd like to be able to send commands to the stdin of that service.

[systemd.exec](https://freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html) says that `StandardInput=file:/path/to/file` is a thing and supports FIFOs.  That sounds like the simplest method.

I've tried this in my `~/.config/systemd/user/foo.service`

```
[Service]
ExecStartPre=mkfifo %t/foo.stdin
ExecStart=cat -
StandardInput=file:%t/foo.stdin
ExecStopPost=rm -f %t/foo.stdin
```

In this example, I expect that when I run the following, I'll see the output echo'd in the journal.

```
echo "hello" > /run/user/1000/foo.stdin
```

I have two problems with this:

1. `foo.service: Failed to set up standard input: No such file or directory` . It appears that `StandardInput=` must exist before `ExecStartPre=`.  Will I need to create a permanent pipe in a static location during installation or is there a work-around?  If I make the file manually, and remove `ExecStartPre`/`ExecStopPost`, then things work.
2. The first `echo "command"` is processed fine, but sends an `EOF` and stdin closes.  I wanted the stdin to remain open.  [The answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/366219/prevent-automatic-eofs-to-a-named-pipe-and-send-an-eof-when-i-want-it) (`exec 3> stdin`, ..., `exec 3>&-`) seems to be to use bash FD redirection, but that isn't available in systemd.

Comment: You can just point `ExecStart` to a shell script that will set up the pipe and chainload the real executable. But if I may challenge the framing, why not use `ncat`/`netcat` and Unix sockets instead of pipes?

Comment: I know how to use `netcat` to listen on a specific port, but I'd prefer the user to log-in (instead of listening to any traffic on that port port).  I haven't used `netcat` with unix sockets.

Comment: The other problem with using netcat, is my service doesn't call `accept()`.  That means `foo.socket` needs `Accept=yes`.  But that means the socket will spawn one instance of the service per connection, then stop the service when the connection completes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a [socket unit](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.socket.html#) for your FIFO:

- `foo.socket`:

  ```
  [Socket]
  ListenFIFO=%t/foo.stdin
  Service=foo.service
  ```
- `foo.service`:

  ```
  [Service]
  ExecStart=/bin/cat -
  Sockets=foo.socket
  StandardInput=socket
  StandardOutput=journal
  StandardError=journal
  ```

Start it up as follows:

```
systemctl --user start foo.socket
```

The service itself will start as soon as the FIFO is written into. If you want it to start immediately, instead launch it like this:

```
systemctl --user start foo.service
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks.  I've never used the `ListenFIFO=` option before.  It's way simpler than I thought.